# How to make a shortcut from CMD?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, command-line, shortcuts

How can I create a shortcut file (`.lnk`) to another file or executable, using command line utilities?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any straightforward way to do that.  Some people have written tools that let you do it; [here's one of them](http://www.xxcopy.com/xxcopy38.htm).  A Google search for "windows create shortcut command line" turns up some others. (I haven't tried any of them.)

Comment: @iglvzx - I'm not sure that the editing you did is correct. I don't think that Shantanu needs a batch script - it could be any way of creating a *.lnk to another *.exe file.

Comment: @alfasin I added `(.ink file)`, as there was some confusion. I revised the question to reflect Shantanu's comment. While you do provide a way to make 'shortcuts', it does not answer this specific question.

Comment: Use the following:  
powershell "$s=(New-Object -COM WScript.Shell).CreateShortcut('%userprofile%\Desktop\shortcut.lnk');$s.TargetPath='C:\Windows\';$s.Save()"















































































Obviously, replace "'%userprofile%\Desktop\shortcut.lnk" and "C:\Windows\" with your shortcut path and target path, respectively.

Comment: @cowlinator As typed, your suggestion does not work.

Comment: @Ploni, it does work for me on my computer.  What error message are you seeing?  What is your powershell execution policy?

Comment: @cowlinator Strange. Now it works for me too.

Comment: That's good to hear, if a bit mystifying.  If anybody else is having issues, you can try typing the following directly into powershell:
$s=(New-Object -COM WScript.Shell).CreateShortcut($Env:userprofile + '\Desktop\shortcut.lnk');$s.TargetPath='C:\Windows\';$s.Save()

Comment: @cowlinator your comment contains multiple zero-width / non-printable characters. As you are asking users to copy and paste this into their command line, this can look quite bad from a security perspective. Please remove them and format your comment as raw string.

Comment: For anyone interested, here is a cleaned version of @cowlinator's comment: `powershell "$s=(New-Object -COM WScript.Shell).CreateShortcut('%userprofile%\Desktop\shortcut.lnk');$s.TargetPath='C:\Windows\';$s.Save()"`

Comment: @zsero, I was concerned about your comment, so I copy/pasted both of my above comments into notepad++ and selected "show all characters", but I found no non-printable characters.  Also, I'd be pretty pretty surprised if stack-exchange sites didn't sanitize their inputs.  What makes you believe there are non-printable characters there?

Comment: @cowlinator in Chrome, right click: Inspect on your text to see it has 3 occurances of `&zwnj;&#8203;` in it.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

There is some very useful information on this site: http://ss64.com/nt/shortcut.html

Seems like there is some `shortcut.exe` in some resource kit which I don't have.
As many other sites mention, there is no built-in way to do it from a batch file.

But you can do it from a VB script:

> Optional sections in the VBscript below are commented out:

```vb
Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sLinkFile = "C:\MyShortcut.LNK"
Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile)
    oLink.TargetPath = "C:\Program Files\MyApp\MyProgram.EXE"
 '  oLink.Arguments = ""
 '  oLink.Description = "MyProgram"   
 '  oLink.HotKey = "ALT+CTRL+F"
 '  oLink.IconLocation = "C:\Program Files\MyApp\MyProgram.EXE, 2"
 '  oLink.WindowStyle = "1"   
 '  oLink.WorkingDirectory = "C:\Program Files\MyApp"
oLink.Save
```

So, if you really **must** do it, then you could make your batch file write the VB script to disk, invoke it and then remove it again. For example, like so:

```
@echo off
echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") > CreateShortcut.vbs
echo sLinkFile = "%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\Desktop\Hello.lnk" >> CreateShortcut.vbs
echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) >> CreateShortcut.vbs
echo oLink.TargetPath = "C:\Windows\notepad.exe" >> CreateShortcut.vbs
echo oLink.Save >> CreateShortcut.vbs
cscript CreateShortcut.vbs
del CreateShortcut.vbs
```

Running the above script results in a new shortcut on my desktop:
[image: Resulting shortcut]

Here's a more complete snippet from an anonymous contributor (updated with a minor fix):

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET LinkName=Hello
SET Esc_LinkDest=%%HOMEDRIVE%%%%HOMEPATH%%\Desktop\!LinkName!.lnk
SET Esc_LinkTarget=%%SYSTEMROOT%%\notepad.exe
SET cSctVBS=CreateShortcut.vbs
SET LOG=".\%~N0_runtime.log"
((
  echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject^("WScript.Shell"^) 
  echo sLinkFile = oWS.ExpandEnvironmentStrings^("!Esc_LinkDest!"^)
  echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut^(sLinkFile^) 
  echo oLink.TargetPath = oWS.ExpandEnvironmentStrings^("!Esc_LinkTarget!"^)
  echo oLink.Save
)1>!cSctVBS!
cscript //nologo .\!cSctVBS!
DEL !cSctVBS! /f /q
)1>>!LOG! 2>>&1
```

Comment: Related: [MSDN, Shell Links](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776891%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: This works great for shortcut to a file. However, i'm having a weird problem using it for shortcut to a folder, when my variable Esc_LinkTarget contains an environment variable trying to get its parent folder. (Something like %CD%\.. does not work, but %CD% works). The shortcut target type becomes a 'File' instead of 'Folder'

Comment: @Edmund Interesting problem. I don't have time to look into it, but I would assume a trailing slash could make a difference.

Comment: Note: if you use `SET Esc_LinkTarget=%0` then you have to remove the `"` from `echo oLink.TargetPath = oWS.ExpandEnvironmentStrings^(!Esc_LinkTarget!^)`

Comment: Instead of creating a vbscript for each execution it would have been far better to use `Wscript.Arguments` to get the command line arguments... lol

Comment: Works like a charm. I liked the "Not complete snippet" more lol

Comment: thank you so much!!

Comment: @Sancarn I have implemented that; also I didn't need to generate and then delete at all, in my case I can just leave the vbscript where it is. however, I am unfortunately unable to post my answer because someone marked this question as protected, and stackoverflow is for some arbitrary reason a separate site from superuser. :( unfortunate because the resulting solution is much simpler than all the others posted here.

Comment: @TamaMcGlinn Indeed, you can suggest edits to other people's answers, but protected threads are always a bit sad. I message to the mods might help getting it unlocked to post your answer :).

Comment: I am almost in tears: what a powerful piece of code!!! I have been trying to create a .lnk in WINE (Linux) to no avail. Your code did the job. I really appreciate that it uses the most basic tools .bat script and visual basic—no need of "power"shell. Thanks!

Answer (score 42):

Here's a similar solution using powershell (I know, you can probably re-write your whole batch file in PS, but if you just want to Get It Done™...)

```
set TARGET='D:\Temp'
set SHORTCUT='C:\Temp\test.lnk'
set PWS=powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile

%PWS% -Command "$ws = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell; $s = $ws.CreateShortcut(%SHORTCUT%); $S.TargetPath = %TARGET%; $S.Save()"
```

You may have to explicity specify the path to PS in your file, but it should work. There are some additional attributes you can mangle through this object, too:

```
Name             MemberType Definition                             
----             ---------- ----------                             
Load             Method     void Load (string)                     
Save             Method     void Save ()                           
Arguments        Property   string Arguments () {get} {set}        
Description      Property   string Description () {get} {set}      
FullName         Property   string FullName () {get}               
Hotkey           Property   string Hotkey () {get} {set}           
IconLocation     Property   string IconLocation () {get} {set}     
RelativePath     Property   string RelativePath () {set}           
TargetPath       Property   string TargetPath () {get} {set}       
WindowStyle      Property   int WindowStyle () {get} {set}         
WorkingDirectory Property   string WorkingDirectory () {get} {set}
```

Comment: [Trix](https://superuser.com/users/337372/trix): If you believe that you have [a better way of doing this](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/702877), just post it as a new answer (linking to this one, if appropriate).

Comment: Very good nswer

Answer (score 23):

Besides shortcut.exe, you can also use the command line version of NirCmd to create shortcut.
http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/shortcut.html

Comment: I recomend almost *everything* from NirSoft, it's the ultimate geek toolset

Answer (score 21):

How about using mklink command ?
C:\Windows\System32>mklink
Creates a symbolic link.

MKLINK [[/D] | [/H] | [/J]] Link Target

```
    /D      Creates a directory symbolic link.  Default is a file
            symbolic link.
    /H      Creates a hard link instead of a symbolic link.
    /J      Creates a Directory Junction.
    Link    specifies the new symbolic link name.
    Target  specifies the path (relative or absolute) that the new link
            refers to.
```

Comment: Good idea, but symlinks appear to behave a bit differently than shortcuts. If I create a shortcut to a Visual Studio solution, it opens all the relatively-pathed-projects correctly. However, if I open the same solution via a symlink, the working directory is that of the path in which the symlink resides, not the path to which it refers.

Comment: Also creating simlink requires admin privilege.

Answer (score 13):

If you have [Git](https://git-scm.com/) installed, it comes bundled with `create-shortcut.exe` which allows you to create shortcuts from the command line, and works in Windows 10. This utility is not AFAICT publicly documented, and the `--help` is minimal:

```
Usage: create-shortcut.exe [options] <source> <destination>
```

However, using Sysinternals's `strings` utility to extract strings from the `.exe`, I was able to work out the `[options]` and the mappings to the fields shown in shortcuts' `Properties` page:

```
--work-dir ('Start in' field)
--arguments (tacked onto the end of the 'Target')
--show-cmd (I presume this is the 'Run' droplist, values 'Normal window', 'Minimised', 'Maximised')
--icon-file (allows specifying the path to an icon file for the shortcut)
--description ('Comment' field)
```

Example usage:

```
REM If bin folder already in your PATH, omit CD line:
cd /d "C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin" 
create-shortcut.exe --work-dir "C:\path\to\files" --arguments "--myarg=myval" "C:\path\to\files\file.ext" "C:\path\to\shortcuts\shortcut.lnk"
```

The `strings` utility also reveals application compatibility with Windows Vista, 7, 8, 8.1 and 10.

For convenience, the `bin` folder can be added to your `PATH` as follows:

```
"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" "[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable(\"PATH\", \"$env:PATH;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\", [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)"
```

(adjust `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin` if `create-shortcut.exe` exists in a different path on your system)

Comment: With the Git I have (verison 2.27.0.windows.1) I had to dig to find this file as it wasn't referenced in PATH. Found in `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin`

Comment: @mattwilkie The path to the exe is indicated in 'Example usage' above, with a note about PATH

Comment: Ahh, I see that now. I missed on first read because text field scrolled off right of screen (and my hasty reading).

Comment: Wouldn't it be more robust to check for `where git.exe`, then use that to determine the correct path of the `create-shortcut.exe` based on that? After all hardcoding paths isn't exactly the smartest idea. Even just using `%ProgramFiles%\Git` in place of `C:\Program Files\Git` would improve this quite a bit.

Comment: If you are scripting it, and are unsure of the environment i.e. where git might be installed to, yes, that would certainly be worthwhile. But the OP's question isn't about scripting the creation of shortcuts, nor is my answer.

Comment: You dont need to install git. You can download standalone binary from https://github.com/git-for-windows/git-sdk-64/blob/main/mingw64/bin/create-shortcut.exe

Comment: just use it under the bash.exe, which is in the git distribution as well. Then all PATH like issues are solved

Comment: Bless you for working out the arguments. I spent hours trying to get arguments to work in this tool, wow. I wish they would document things properly.

Answer (score 11):

After all the discussions we had here, this is my suggested solution:
download: http://optimumx.com/download/Shortcut.zip
extract it on your desktop (for example).
Now, suppose you want to create a shortcut for a file called scrum.pdf (also on desktop):
1. open CMD and go to desktop folder
2. run: `Shortcut.exe /f:"%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\sc.lnk" /a:c  /t:%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\scrum.pdf`

it will create a shortcut called sc.lnk on your desktop that will point to the original file (scrum.pdf)

Comment: That's not a shortcut; it's just a batch file that invokes a specified program.

Comment: a shortcut is something you run from windows, since he used CMD in the title and put the tag "command-line" I assumed he wants to run it from CMD. A batch file is the equivalent of a windows "shortcut" when you run in CMD (dos like) env.

Comment: Since he put "shortcut (.lnk file)" in the body of the question, I assumed he wants to create an actual shortcut.

Comment: sorry for clarity i wanted to have a icon on my desktop that i made in cmd that would be a shortcut to a exe file

Comment: now that I finally understood (slow thinker - what can you do...) I changed my answer. hope it helps!

Comment: @twasbrillig works for me...

Comment: Works for Windows 11

Answer (score 2):

You can create an easy .vbs script that is right for you:

Shortcut.vbs

```
If WScript.Arguments.Count <> 2 Then WScript.Quit 1
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
TargetPath = FSO.GetAbsolutePathName(WScript.Arguments(0))
WorkingDirectory = FSO.GetParentFolderName(TargetPath)
Set lnk = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").CreateShortcut(WScript.Arguments(1))
    lnk.TargetPath = TargetPath
    lnk.WorkingDirectory = WorkingDirectory
    lnk.Save
```

From command line or batch script enter this command:

```
wscript Shortcut.vbs file.txt file.lnk
```

Answer (score 1):

This free program has required functionality http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd2.html: (sample from said web page)
`"Create a shortcut to Windows calculator under Start Menu->Programs->Calculators   nircmd.exe shortcut "f:\winnt\system32\calc.exe" "~$folder.programs$\Calculators" "Windows Calculator"`

My own sample to try: nircmd.exe shortcut "c:\windows\system32\calc.exe" "~$folder.desktop$" "Windows Calculator"

Answer (score -1):

I know this topic is old but I wanted to provide the simple solution that worked for me.

I first copied the .ico file to my C: drive.  Then I created the shortcut on my desktop and set the icon to the ico file on my C: drive.  I then copied both the .ico and shortcut to a network share that my users have access to.  Once there I wrote the following batch file to copy the ico and .url to the users windows 7 desktop. This creates the shortcut on all users desktop and keeps the icon file I set when creating the shortcut.  I hope this helps someone.

```
@echo off
Copy "\\sharename\folder\icon.ico" "C:\"
pause
copy "\\sharename\folder\shortcut.url" "C:\Users\All Users\Desktop"
pause
```

Comment: If this is the approach to take, it is better to create the actual shortcut (.lnk)  which embeds the icon in it. That shortcut can then be copied everywhere.

Answer (score -1):

**Step 1:** Open CMD file location

[image]

---

**Step 2:** Right click properties on Command Prompt, and set favorite shortcut like this:

[image]

Comment: While I can understand the confusion, the question is about creating the "shortcut file" or "link file" (extension .lnk) of a shortcut itself. Your answer explains how to give an existing shortcut file a keyboard "shortcut". Your answer does not fit the question. But I will not downvote. It is well written and pictured and was given in good faith. I'd say it deserves an upvote just for the effort taken to compose it.

Comment: Upvote given. At least, it does not deserve a negative score.