# How to show/hide the My Computer icon on the desktop via the command line?

Tags: command-line, windows-8, icons, desktop

How I can show or hide the Computer (My Computer) icon on the desktop from CMD?

Comment: Do you specifically need `.lnk` shortcut or any other `.bat` or something that can launch My Computer will do?

Comment: No, I want to enable Computer icon in desktop icons in windows 8

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/392061/how-to-make-a-shortcut-from-cmd

Comment: @bummi this post create shortcut but I want to show read Computer icon with Manage option on right click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

1. To **hide** the icon:

   ```
   reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\ClassicStartMenu /v {20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D} /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f

   reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel /v {20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D} /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
   ```
2. To **show** the icon:

   ```
   reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\ClassicStartMenu /v {20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D} /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f

   reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel /v {20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D} /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
   ```