# Creating template folders for filing a project

Tags: windows-7

I work on many projects.  Projects have a start and an end.  What I am attempting to do is create a template Windows Explorer folder for common filing per project.  What I than do is copy this template when starting a new project.  The problem I run into is all the shortcuts created for ease of navigating within the project folder always lead back to the template instead of the new project's folder copy.  Is there a way to copy off the template where the shortcuts stay within the new copy?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't copy shortcuts and folders, but you should create them:

- Folders with md commandline command.
- Shortcuts like in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/392061/how-to-make-a-shortcut-from-cmd).