# How to autostart and autoconnect OpenVPN in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, openvpn

Windows 10 startup seems to be strange, or at least new.  Many programs don't autostart the way they did in previous versions, and a lot of people are asking how to get things to autostart.  I know, because I'm constantly looking to autostart my programs I'm used to.

How can I get OpenVPN to start on boot, prevent Internet access until it's connected, and automatically log in to an OVPN profile?

I already have the credentials saved in a text file, so OpenVPN just needs to load the file, process it, and connect.

I used to have this working on Windows 7, but it seems I've forgotten how to do it,

Comment: How you configure an application to start, when a user logs into their profile, has remained unchanged since Windows XP was released.  What have you specifically tried?  *Update your question.*

Answer (score 40):

The best way is to use services:

1. Install the OpenVPN service when you install the client;
2. Place your OpenVPN profiles (with the extension .ovpn, not .conf as is common on Linux) in the config subdirectory of the OpenVPN installation directory, probably `C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config`.
3. Open the Services console (`services.msc`);
4. Find OpenVPNService, right click on it, Properties, and change startup type from “Manual” to “Automatic”.
5. Start the service, and OpenVPN will find and connect to the profiles in any .ovpn files. **Keep in mind in most situations you need one TUN/TAP interface per connection file.** In windows, I strongly advise to permanently associate an interface with their connection using the configuration files:
   `dev-node TAP_Serv` forces OpenVPN to bind the connection to the network interface named "Tap_Serv". Added after reading some comments: You need one interface per connection. In Linux this is trivial, but in windows it may be problematic. HAving two configurations that you can SEPARATEDLY test succesfully, doesn't mean they'll run together, as they may be competing for the same interface. OpenVPN is a ported program, and windows driver subsystem has allways been a pain in the a**.

You may want to investigate if there's a way to elaborate a whitelist to force the service to connect only to specific files, and not all. I've had some issues in the past with people who needed to have a VPN server as a service plus several vpn client files in the same machine that only connect  every now and then. In those situations, if I wanted OpenVPN GUI to show them a beautifull list of available connections, it meant that the service saw those files and was trying to connect to them automatically. In those cases, I decided not to use services at all:

If using a service is not an option, you can pass extra command line arguments to the OpenVPN GUI invocation to make it automatically connect on startup (as well as showing the tray icon as usual):

```
openvpn-gui.exe --connect myprofile.ovpn
```

To get that to run when you log in, place such a shortcut in the usual startup folder. (For all users, `%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`; or for the current user only, `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.)

---

I don’t know how to avoid the user to connect to the Internet before the VPN is set. The only way I can figure out if through Windows Firewall, and I'm not an expert on that subject. If you want to avoid a poweruser to be able to get to the Internet you need a firewall in your gateway to avoid so, or strong group policies to avoid privilege scalation.

For a normal user, you can configure the Windows client machine without a default gateway. Set a persistent static route to the VPN server on Windows clients using the following command (-P makes it persistent):

```
route -P add <target> mask <netmask> <gateway IP> metric <metric cost> if <interface>
```

Routes in Windows are stored under the following registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\PersistentRoutes
```

At this point a disconnected client only has access to the VPN server. Then you can add the following lines in the VPN server configuration file to add routes on clients when they connect:

To configure the VPN server as the default gateway:

```
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
```

To add a specific route through the VPN Server:

```
push "route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0"
```

Sometimes route pushing doesn't work on Windows. When this happens to me, I completly uninstall OpenVPN and its interfaces from Windows, restart the system and install the latest version of the software. Then, before establishing the first connection, I restart Windows. This has always solved the issues. However, Windows 10 Anniversary update (1607) is buggy with OpenVPN. There's a link to a deeper discussion in OpenVPN forums:

[Connection problems with Windows 10 anniversary update](https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?t=22253)

Keep that in mind when you setup your Windows 10 OpenVPN clients.

If you're a consultant looking to give advice to a client, please consider using some specific NATIVE Windows solutions, if your client's budget allows for it. I won't name any to avoid being flagged, but most known networking hardware companies offer solutions compatible with their devices that provide native drivers for any edge OS you may think of. Disclaimer: I don't work for any of those companies. For my own dialy life I use OpenVPN, but to remotely connect to my company they've a commercial solution bundled on the computers: I never had a single connection issue, while OpenVPN is usually more delicate. Don't take me wrong, I've delivered OpenVPN to production environments for clients with total success, but you need to be extra cautious (and put watchdog and recoverfy measures in place, or just train the user to "click reconnect" if something doesn't work properly).

Comment: You could use the route command to force all traffic through the VPN. See http://www.comentum.com/route.html

Comment: I consider myself a power user, but I'd like to be able to set this up for nonpower users and have it work seamlessly too.  I don't need to prevent other power users from tinkering.

Comment: "The OpenVPN service will look into the config directory and connect to every VPN profile that is stored here."  That doesn't seem to be the case.  It seems to be that it connects to the first one, when they are sorted alphabetically.  Can you link to documentation?  I can't find a section that covers that.

Comment: Hello Dan. Most of my experience comes from OpenVPN servers in CentOS, and whenever I store multiple server files it runs them all. I'll conduct a test to determine if the behaviour with client files is the same, but I've no reason to think it will be different. Sorry if I misleaded you, will report back ASAP (I'm at work right now, either when I've some free time or after work i'll check it on a Windows machine).

Comment: If you want an user not to be able to connect to the Internet until the VPN is up, you could leave his default gateway unconfigured and set a static persistent route to the VPN server. Once the VPN client is connected, you can use the "push" to add routes through the VPN on clients. I'm editing my initial answer to cover this

Comment: Oh, BTW, the service is not the same thing as the GUI, and the service doesn't give you the option to pick a different profile later, nor does it give you any kind of feedback.

Comment: Also Task Scheduler (<kbd>Windows key</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, type`Taskschd.msc` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>) can be used.

Comment: Is there a way that the OpenVPN GUI can 'see' the active connections made by the service?

Comment: @deed02392 not that I know, sorry.

Comment: @YetAnotherRandomUser sorry I initially missed your comment. I've never seen it in the documentation, however, in my experfience thats what happens. Normally, as you only have ONE TUN/TAP interface, only the first bind success, so, yes, only the first connection is used, but thats caused because both connections want to exclusively bind to the same interface. With proper configuration files, every connection is stablished, which has been a pain in the a** for me. I've edited the original post. Sometimes is it not the first file the one that wins the race to bind to the interface, giving probs

Comment: @YetAnotherRandomUser There is a README.txt in C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config which mentions "When OpenVPN is started as a service, a separate OpenVPN process will be instantiated for each configuration file." and "When OpenVPN GUI is started configs in this directory are added to the list of available connections."

Comment: This approach sounds promising but does not work on my machine with Windows 10 and the v2.5.2 OpenVPN Community client (https://openvpn.net/community-downloads/). The client installs an "OpenVPN Interactive Service", but the service description says that it simply provide connection functionalities to the OpenVPN GUI that runs in non-privileged mode. The outcome is that I put my config and certs, etc. in the above places and check that the service is already set to automatically start. Yet nothing happens when my system starts.

Comment: I know my configs are correct, because if I manually start the OpenVPN GUI and double click on its taskbar icon, it automatically connects to my server with no problem. Also, I can manually run the CLI client `openvpn.exe` with my config file, no problem either. I am also sure that my configs are in the shared location under "Program Files", not in my user specific location.

Answer (score 4):

Don't know if this is still relevant, but since OpenVPN 2.5.0 you can just put the config under "config-auto" instead of "config" and the connection will be brought up automatically when the service starts. No extra scripts or autostart required.

Comment: Everything is allways relevant. My dad just asked me abvout this and came back to my own post to check some commands, and your answer made my day :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to run it as a service, you can just copy [DGoikos second answer](https://superuser.com/a/1166051/1495105) and run it in a batch-file (e.g. openVPNautostart.bat). Simple if you want to send it around and have people run the script manually **as administrators**.
I stole some code from [here](https://superuser.com/a/392082/1495105) and adapted it to openVPN. If you're using regular install settings it should work.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET LinkName=OpenVPN
SET Esc_LinkDest=%%ProgramData%%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\openvpn-gui.lnk
SET Esc_LinkTarget=%%ProgramFiles%%\OpenVPN\bin\openvpn-gui.exe
SET cSctVBS=CreateShortcut.vbs
SET LOG=".\%~N0_runtime.log"
((
  echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject^("WScript.Shell"^)
  echo sLinkFile = oWS.ExpandEnvironmentStrings^("!Esc_LinkDest!"^)
  echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut^(sLinkFile^)
  echo oLink.TargetPath = oWS.ExpandEnvironmentStrings^("!Esc_LinkTarget!"^)
  echo oLink.Save
)1>!cSctVBS!
cscript //nologo .\!cSctVBS!
DEL !cSctVBS! /f /q
)1>>!LOG! 2>>&1
```

To edit the shortcut location (for all users/only current user) you can edit `%%ProgramData%%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\openvpn-gui.lnk` (all users) to `%%APPDATA%%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\openvpn-gui.lnk` (current user).

Comment: nice solution. Saving the template for future :)