# Automatically connecting to multiple sites using OpenVPN Client upon login

Tags: windows-10, networking, router, vpn, openvpn

I already have OpenVPN set to start automatically. That was easy enough, as there is a checkbox in settings, which automatically sets the OpenVPN service to automatic. I tried that out by restarting the desktop and it works.

I have several (4 at the moment) connection scripts. OpenVPN stores them nicely in the config folder. I can select "Connect" to the appropriate site and I get a connection. I set up silent. That works nicely too.

What I could not figure out how to do is that OpenVPN automatically connects to my sites, when I login to my computer.

I have my OVPN extension files stored nicely in my folder:

```
C:\Users\<user>\OpenVPN\config
```

I did research and came up with OpenVPN Server, but I am not interested in going the other way. I just want to automatically connect to the server, when I log into the computer.

OpenVPN Settings

[image: OpenVPN Client Settings Tab]

OpenVPN About

[image: OpenVPN About Box Tab]

OpenVPN Log On

[image: OpenVPN Log On Tab]

My research turned up the following command, which I thought to schedule a minute or two after my computer starts.

```
openvpn-gui.exe --connect C:\Users\username\OpenVPN\config\ClientConnection1\clientconnection1.ovpn
```

I can discount the line above for two reasons.

1. I tried the command after OpenVPN was started and it did not work. Yes, I tried from an Administrative command window. I am not surprised as OpenVPN is already started. That gets me into point #2. (Yes, I realize that I can start OpenVPN manually and have Task Scheduler run the above command.)
2. I want to automatically connect on my desktop to 4 (could be any number) of sites automatically and the command line offers support for one.

How is that achieved?

Thoughts?

**strong text**UPDATE

Per the below comment, I copied my script files to the `config-auto` folder as follows:

```
C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config-auto
    client-connect1 (a subdirectory)
    README.txt
C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config-auto\client-connect1
    caConnection1.crt
    clientConnection1.crt
    clientConnection1.key
    clientConnection1.ovpn
```

The contents of the script are:

```
client
dev tap
proto udp
dev-node NETGEAR-VPN
remote connection1.ddns.net 12974
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
key-direction 1
persist-key
persist-tun
ca caConnection1.crt
cert clientConnection1.crt
key clientConnection1.key
cipher AES-128-CBC
comp-lzo
verb 5
```

As stated, the script works when placed in either `config` folder.

I restarted the computer (twice now) with the config files in the `config-auto` folder as shown above, and nothingness, even after 5-minutes waiting.

I did see, thank you, this `README.txt` file in the `config-auto` directory substantiating the comment, just it does not work.

```
This directory or its subdirectories should contain OpenVPN
configuration files each having an extension of .ovpn
that should be automatically started at boot up.

When OpenVPNService is started, a separate OpenVPN
process will be instantiated for each configuration file.

OpenVPN GUI does not scan this directory.
```

**UPDATE**

I found the log file and here is the problem, so progress, just have to solve it now.

```
2021-04-10 18:26:50 WARNING: Compression for receiving enabled. Compression has been used in the past to break encryption. Sent packets are not compressed unless "allow-compression yes" is also set.
2021-04-10 18:26:50 us=900373 DEPRECATED OPTION: --cipher set to 'AES-128-CBC' but missing in --data-ciphers (AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM). Future OpenVPN version will ignore --cipher for cipher negotiations. Add 'AES-128-CBC' to --data-ciphers or change --cipher 'AES-128-CBC' to --data-ciphers-fallback 'AES-128-CBC' to silence this warning.
Options error: --ca fails with 'catheclient.crt': No such file or directory (errno=2)
Options error: --cert fails with 'clienttheclient.crt': No such file or directory (errno=2)
2021-04-10 18:26:50 us=900373 WARNING: cannot stat file 'clienttheclient.key': No such file or directory (errno=2)
Options error: --key fails with 'clienttheclient.key': No such file or directory (errno=2)
Options error: Please correct these errors.
Use --help for more information.
```

1. OpenVPN continuously attempts to connect, not just once. The log file shows connection attempts every minute or so.
2. The 3 files in question are in the same directory, a subdirectory of the config/auto-config folder. I might need to hard code the entire path.

Comment: Try the `\Program Files\OpenVPN\config-auto` folder for your `.ovpn` configuration files. This should start a separate OpenVPN process on each file.

Comment: @harrymc Thank you for the quick comment. Does not work, see `update` on my question. I placed the config file in the `config-auto` directory. I did not see that directory yesterday. I did see the README.txt file, which says the same thing as what you wrote. I MOVED the config files there, restarted the computer (twice), waited about 5-minutes, and nothing. If I copy the files back to either config folder and restart the GUI, then I am able to manually connect. I did verify that `OpenVPN Service` does start after the reboot.

Comment: Have you installed and started the OpenVPNService? OpenVPN needs to be installed as a service, see [Running OpenVPN as a Windows Service](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/running-openvpn-as-a-windows-service/).

Comment: @harrymc I stated in my question and my last comment that the `OpenVPNService` starts nicely and is set to automatic. I am happy to furnish a screenshot if you want, though I do not wish to make the question overtly long.

Comment: Automatic might start too early. Try manual.

Comment: @harrymc nope. I set the GUI and service to manually start. I then restarted the PC. Waited for it to finish logging in, started the service, waited a couple of minutes (more than enough time), and nada. Is there some sort of log that the service uses?

Comment: (1) Did you keep copies of the `.ovpn` files in both folders when starting OpenVPNService (just in case)? (2) Try also folder `C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config`. (3) See also [openvpnserv2](https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpnserv2).

Comment: @harrymc Having the config files in all 3 locations then starting up the service and the UI has no effect on the problem. I downloaded the OpenVPN service or whatever, so building should not do anything. What would be more meaningful is to know where I can look at the `OpenVPN Service` auto connect log files. The GUI has an explicit log file to show what it does. I have no clue what the service does or does not do.

Comment: @harrymc The question, https://superuser.com/questions/1166026/how-to-autostart-and-autoconnect-openvpn-in-windows-10, seems to relate. My config file has a dev-node line, which is the name that I gave on the server. I also see the `dev tap` line. Side question, how did you insert a URL nicely into your comment?

Comment: I found the log file: https://openvpn.net/community-resources/running-openvpn-as-a-windows-service/.

Comment: @harrymc success, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log file definitely helped, however the [OpenVPN Notes](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/running-openvpn-as-a-windows-service/) page is slightly incorrect.

1. The `OpenVPN Service` looks at the `config-auto` first and ignores, at least by the same name, contents in the `config` folder.
2. I had to hard code the path, so:

   client
   dev tap
   proto udp
   dev-node NETGEAR-VPN
   remote theclient2.ddns.net 12974
   resolv-retry infinite
   nobind
   key-direction 1
   persist-key
   persist-tun
   ca "C:/Program Files/OpenVPN/config/client-Th/caTheClient2.crt"
   cert "C:/Program Files/OpenVPN/config/client-TheClient2/clientTheClient2.crt"
   key "C:/Program Files/OpenVPN/config/client-TheClient2/clientTheClient2.key"
   cipher AES-128-CBC
   comp-lzo
   verb 5

I use a forward slash, as I have experience with Linux based tools, even ported to Windows, that they do not like the Windows backslashes, even sometimes if doubled, so I just KISS and used a forward slash.

I then opened a command/terminal window, and issued "ping 10.0.0.1" and success!

The log files stays static, no new entries.

Finally.