# Install a shortcut using a software installer?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, installation, setup

I am trying to create a simple install program that will put a file (shortcut) with the following in the target so that it will open a chromeless window to a website.

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --app=https://example.com

When I create the shortcut on my desktop or in a local folder it will work. I am trying to take the same file I created and place it in a folder using a install setup program.

I tried Inno installer and it gave me an error when I tried to compile.

https://www.screencast.com/t/ruIYCAfMrj

Is there a way to accomplish what I am looking for in order to install it using a software installer program?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

=============

What I am attempting to do is get the shortcut I made on my local machine onto others machines so when they open double click on them it will open chrome to the url in a chromeless window without navigation address bar or buttons. It will look and act like an app.

To replicate what I do on my local machine here are instructions to create the type of shortcut I want to install on others windows machines.

Create Windows 10 chromeless app windows.

Create a new shortcut by right clicking on a empty area of your desktop.

Select New and then Shortcut.

https://www.screencast.com/t/wSGzzcre

In location field Define your website target...

Add the following from this next line...

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --app=http://live.kslx.com/listen/

Change url after --app= to any page you want to be the start page in the window you are creating

Submit and in next field type the name of your App/shortcut

https://www.screencast.com/t/vAo2JkVK

Click finish button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in the sccreencast-link clearly states that you have a problem with the quotes (") in the line that starts with "Source" - maybe check that?

But that aside, i create installers i need using [InstallForge](https://installforge.net/). It's free, can be used with a GUI, can be used with config files - and easily allows to create arbitrary shortcuts during the installation process. I don't know if it fits your needs, but maybe it's worth a look.

In general, "creating a shortcut" isn't really "creating an installer" and i don't really understand what you want to achieve. Maybe you can clarify?

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. I edited my question to provide instructions on the shortcut I make in an effort for you to attempt yourself a possible solution to add the shortcut to an installable setup program that would place the shortcut on someones start menu and desktop.

Thanks again.

Comment: All you want is a shortcut. A simple, plain shortcut. Do that by creating a little script that will create the needed shortcut. You can do that using various methods, see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/392061/how-to-make-a-shortcut-from-cmd) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30028709/how-do-i-create-a-shortcut-via-command-line-in-windows) or [here](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/FileCreateShortcut.htm).

Comment: Thank you. This points me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in Windows, I guess the simplest form of installer would be a Windows batch file. Do you have experience in creating batch files?

In a batch file you could create a shortcut using the Nircmd program from Nirsoft.com.

Syntax for the command can be found here: [Nircmd syntax](https://nircmd.nirsoft.net/shortcut.html)

This may or may not be practical for you - it would mean you need to put Nircmd on each machine on which the simple installer is to be run. Worthwhile if you are administering a work group - Nircmd is very useful for a wide range of purposes.

Another approach might be to use powershell and windows scripting which comes on most computers nowadays. But you do need to set powershell up correctly - it's security model is pretty tight. Someone else may be able to help with that - I am not an expert. However here is a link with some relevant code. [Powershell script](https://www.pdq.com/blog/pdq-deploy-and-powershell/)

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. I edited my question to provide instructions on the shortcut I make in an effort for you to attempt yourself a possible solution to add the shortcut to an installable setup program that would place the shortcut on someones start menu and desktop.

Thanks again.

Comment: I was looking into the batch file before seeing your comment here. I found a couple of solutions I think either will work. This one here https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000435.htm and this one here http://bat2exe.net

The issue for me is now trying to figure out how to write the code into the bat file for the shortcut example described above.

Comment: NP Richard. Sorry few more questions. Might you wish to create further batch programs for this group of computers in future? How big is the group? What is earliest windows version? Could you clarify why you are looking at batch to exe converters? Caution is needed with some of these by the way - some work differently than expected (create an exe that calls a batch!), others can have unwanted behaviors according to my AV program.

Comment: I am building a social network site within a niche. I have made sure that it is mobile responsive. Anyone with a browser can access it on their computers. My goal is not for them to type in a browser url but to click on an icon that I install that will open into a chromeless window so that it looks and feels like an app. Just wanted to have a branded install file that stores the shortcut as described that opens in its own container window without address bar or buttons. The reason I was looking into batch to exe converters was because I created a shortcut locally in a folder.

Comment: I then chose the folder and the shortcut file within it to be wrapped into a install program so that when it was ran by the end user it would get installed on their local machine and a shortcut to the shortcut that I gave them would open chrome with the --app=https://website.com as part of the path within the shortcut. It didnt work so I was looking into a batch solution. As far as earliest versions I am not sure as I will offer it to my site visitors as an option to install my site. whatever solution I can work out I will let them know it doesnt work for pcs prior to x etc. Does this help?